# local variable 'texts' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

This a code to extract Unicode values from text files but it gives me following error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import codecs
    import os
    #from urllib import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    ##import nltk
    #def remove_content_li(input_document) :

        #soup = BeautifulSoup(input_document)


    def  extract_unicode(input):
        _ascii_letters = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]', flags=re.UNICODE)
        symbols = re.compile(r'[{} &+( )" =!.?.:.. / |  » © : >< #  «  ,] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 _ - + ; [ ]  %',flags=re.UNICODE)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(input,'r'),'lxml')
        for li in soup.find_all('li'):
            li.decompose()
            texts = soup.findAll(text=True)



        def contains_unicode(text):
            try:
                str(text)
            except:
                return True
            return False

        result = '  '.join((text for text in texts if contains_unicode(texts)))
        result =_ascii_letters.sub(" ", result)
        result = symbols.sub(" ",result)
        ##print(result)
    ##    result = nltk.clean_html(result)
        result.replace('*', '')
```

This is the error I get

```
File "e3.py", line 50, in <module>
    extract_unicode((os.path.join(dirname, filename)))
  File "e3.py", line 30, in extract_unicode
    result = '  '.join((text for text in texts if contains_unicode(texts)))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'texts' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: For your first line in `extract_uniucode(input):`, declare `texts = []` and see if you get different results

Answer (score 4):

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. You're using a variable `texts` before you define it. Perhaps `soup.find_all('li')` is returning an empty list, since you only set `texts` if it finds something.

Comment: I dont understand what is happening

Comment: Like the error says, _you aren't setting texts before using it_. If `soup.find_all('li')` doesn't return anything, `texts` will be undefined. You are assuming that `soup.find_all` is finding things, and that assumption seems to be false.